# Check if a specfic element has specific jquery method attached

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have the following jQuery code. What I am trying to do is perform an if statement to see if **$("#div3").slideToggle("slow");** exists - and if so, to not execute it. Basically, the code a level up from this is run various times during a page view. So if #button is clicked, after the parent "click function" is click more than once, #div3 will toggle many times. I have found other work arounds such as unbinding the element. However, i can't do that or other workarounds for various reasons, as it will affect my other code. There are many more methods going on than this single one within the code I showed. Is there a way to check if  **$("#div3").slideToggle("slow");** already is existing in the current page? Thanks!

```
$('#button').click(function() {
$("#div3").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Okay - i think you have to clearify what you are trying to do, what your code says is "if someone clicks the button, then slideToggle it slowly". Do you want to stay it open? Or what is your Intention?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skitols/29LsL/           OK - here is an example. If you click the first button more than once, and then click the second button, #div2 toggle multiple times. I only want it to toggle once. I would like to make this happen with an IF statement so that I don't have to change my code much. Thanks!

Comment: To be more specific - I need the if statement to be within the #button2 click function - because in my actual code there are other functions that I do want to happen when #button2 is clicked.

Comment: Okay - you register functions on button click and you want that function only registered once. Correct?

Comment: yes - exactly. The user will be clicking #button many times - This is what activates #button2. But that single function within #button2.click should only happen once

Comment: I was hoping it would work like this: if($('#div2').slideToggle("slow")==null){
    $("#div2").slideToggle("slow");
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a function exists by using this:

```
$("#div3").slideToggle == null
```

Especially you can check if an event is bound with:

```
$("#div3").data("events").click == null
```

Alternatively you can just add a new property to $('#div3') like so:

```
$("#div3").clickEventHasBeenAdded = true;
if(!$("#div3").clickEventHasBeenAdded) {
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. If I type that into Firebug for THIS page, it says "false". That method doesn't exist here - shouldn't it say true, as that function is null?

Comment: I used the IE10 Console to test it: "$(document).someFunctionWichDoesNotExist == null" and it returned "true"

Comment: Ahhh - thanks so much! Not sure why I didn't think of adding a new property. All of those help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***HTML***

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
    <div id="div1">item 1</div>
    <div id="div2">item 2</div>
    <div id="div3">item 3</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#div3').slideToggle("slow");
    </script>
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if($('#div3').slideToggle("slow")!=null){
       alert('true');  
    } else{alert('false');}
});
```

***http://jsfiddle.net/e3aHc/3/***

Comment: @kyle do you want this? if not please inform.

Comment: still playing around - I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

```
$(document).one('click', '#button', function() {
    $("#div3").slideToggle("slow");
});
```